# No Connection String Could Be Found In The Application Config File Class Library

Tags: c#, .net, ef-code-first

Currently I'm creating a new Solution with 1 Class Library Project. I installed EntityFramework 6.4.4 and add App.config that only contains 1 Connection String. When I run following command:

```
Enable-Migrations -ConnectionStringName AppDbContext
```

App.Config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="AppDbContext" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=MY_DATABASE;Integrated Security=SSPI;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"/>
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

I got result:
**No Connection String Could Be Found In The Application Config File**

What could have gone wrong?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: What is your startup project? The app.config file should be added there, not to a class library.

Comment: Hi @AMA

I only added 1 Class Library Project to configure Code First, should I just create another project that consume this Class Library?